# Find $\|B\|_{\ell^1 \rightarrow \ell^1} $

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

$B(a_1,a_2,...)=(a_1/1,a_2/2,\ldots, a_n/n,\ldots) $

This is a linear operator defined on $\ell^1$.

---

Notice that $\|Bx\|=\sum |a_n/n| \le \sum |a_n| =\|x\|$.

So $\|B\|=\sup_{\|x\|_1 \le 1} \|Bx\|_1 \le \sup_{\|x\|_1 \le 1} \|x\|_1 \le 1$.

Let $x=(1,0,0,\ldots)$ so $\|B\| \ge \|Bx\|_1 =1$.

So it equals $1$? Is this correct?

Comment: No, of course not. $\|Bx\|_1 = 1/n$.

Comment: what is wrong with mine?

Comment: What is $n$?. I'd actually guess you meant $B(a_1,a_2,...)=(a_1/1,a_2/2,...)$, right?

Comment: @NateRiver oh god, yes i did!

Comment: Btw your analysis looks correct.

Comment: Now it's correct.